# Data inserts to database and then app crashes

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am learning how to send data across to an external database and the code works however it is a little buggy to say the least. I am using [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/) tutorial and a lot of the code has since depreciated so I have been trying to update it myself.

What should happen is when the user hits the sync button the data held in the SQLite database should be sent across to the external database. This happens but then the app crashes. The solution is not clear to me in the log cat and I'm unsure how to rectify the problem. I have managed to isolate the crash to this section of code which was one of the lines of code that was depreciated (on success, on failure).

I have done research on the AsyncHTTPResponseHandler and thought that the code was fine and as I said earlier it does connect to the DB and inserts into the table but then immediately crashes. I have put the code that I think is the problem, along with the log cat.

```
public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB() {
    //Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.getAllUsers();
    if (userList.size() != 0) {
        if (controller.dbSyncCount() != 0) {
            prgDialog.show();
            params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
            client.post("http://jakebreen.co.uk/android/sqlitemysqlsync/inseruser.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    try {
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println(arr.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                            controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(), obj.get("status").toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Log cat

```
              --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.year2.sqlitemysqlsync, PID: 2281
              java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onUserException(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:304)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:395)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
                  at com.year2.sqlitemysqlsync.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:102)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
                  at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
```

try

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(new String(response));
```

Comment: Thanks, that has managed to stop the app from crashing however now in the log cat I can see W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: That would mean your object is not really a JSONArray or there are some unwanted characters. You can try this 
new JSONObject("{" + new String(response) + "}")

Or... post an example of your response. What's really there.

Comment: Thank you for all your advice, everything is now working as expected!